# Open Safari Push Notifications in Chrome

Tags: safari, google-chrome, notifications, apns

I got used to Safari Push Notifications, because they will show up even when Safari itself is closed.
In the last time, I changed to Chrome and now, when I click on a notification, Safari will always open.
Is it possible to config the Safari Push Notifications in that way that that will open the specific website in Chrome?

Some Information about my environment:
- MacBook Air 3,2 (End 2010)
- OS X 10.9.2
- Chrome is default browser

Thank you!

Comment: Is chrome set as your default browser? (can be set in safari's settings). I'm not sure if that works however

Comment: @Kevin Grabher I updated the question

Comment: The choice of default browsers has exactly nothing to do with issues surrounding push notifications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible.

Safari's push notifications are specific to Safari, and so cannot be configured to open in Chrome. It's a part of individual apps and their implementation of the push notification system.

You haven't specified which Apple OS you are using, but I can talking from my experience of iOS. I don't know if push notifications are a thing in OSX.

Comment: Yes OS X has notifications and yes they are specific to the application.

Comment: Thanks @tubedogg, I have never actually used any version of OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Default Browser to chrome and that should work :0

Comment: While your answer might be correct, it would be nice if you could explain bit more or provide references.

Comment: Changing the default browser in settings does not work. This should be obvious! I have the same problem, and my Safari locks up every time I open it. So push notifications are next to obsolete for me.
I'm guessing that since the push notifications originate from Safari, the option of opening them in another browser is not an option.